# Unable to install pygal in python 3.4.3 windows machine

Tags: python, windows, pygal

I tried to install pygal on my windows system running python 3.4.3. It gives me an error related to upgrading my python to 3.5

Code I typed for installation is: python -m pip install --user pygal
Error that I get : RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required

pygal.org website says pygal is available python 2.7 and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and pypy

Anyone with a solution to this problem please, I would be very glad to hear from you

Comment: Please share the entirety of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think -m is unnecessary .Try this on your terminal;

```
pip install pygal
```

If it doesnt works try to download from git with this command;

```
git clone git://github.com/Kozea/pygal.git
```